# Need to get my text to fit around the div image

Tags: html, css

I need to get my text to fit around my div on the this [page](http://jbussey.co.uk/bobbin/bridal.html).

```
<div id="othermain">
Is your big day approaching? Need a Wedding Dress, Bridesmaid Dress or any Bridal Wear altering or remodelling? You are definitely looking in the right place, this is our speciality! </p><br><br> At Bobbin Alterations, 
we want to make sure that your dress is the perfect fit and style for you, for your special occasion. whether it be a Wedding, Prom, a dinner or any other special occasion. We understand that planning you're
big celebration can be very demanding at times, but we're here to take your worries away and make it as stress free as possible.<br><br> Looking good and comfortability is crucial, and with our help, we can tailor and alter a dress the highlights your features and make you feel wonderful.
    <div id="testimonial"></div>
    <br><br>Our standard dress alterations include:<br>
    <br> - Shortening
    <br> - Seams
    <br> - Hemlines
    <br> - Beading
    <br> - Shoulder Adjustments
    <br> - Straps
    <br> - Veils
    <br> - Zips<br>
    <br>We've had the privilege of helping with endless amounts of weddings and proms and take extreme pride in the happiness that is made through our work.<br>
    <br><br>Use the Order form to place an order, or call us on 01325 59976 with an Enquiry, to guarantee a First Class service and a truly memorable occasion.
</div>
```

Above is my code for bridal.html and below is my css code for the two elements in question:

```
#testimonial{background: url(../img/testimonial.fw.png); width: 700px; height: 300px; margin-left:320px;  display: block; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#ordermain {width:1024px; height: 700px}
```

All help is greatly appreciated. I have tried numerous methods. THanks

Comment: Your link requires login

Comment: @user3404065 you can add padding to your id='othermain' it should work that way. And put ALL your text in a tag, a tip for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the left margin and make the div float right.

```
#testimonial{
background: url(../img/testimonial.fw.png);
width: 700px;
height: 300px;
display: block;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: right;
}
```